# How many different possibilities for ordering distinct sorted elements

Tags: combinatorics

Quick question -

How many ways do we have to place $m$ men and $w$ women in a queue, all with different heights, such that all men are placed in ascending order of heights between themselves and all women are placed in ascending order of heights between themselves?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the men need to be in asending order between themselves and they all have different heights, they can't swap position. Therefore it is only the location of men that is relevant. The same argument holds for women. So the problem comes down to align $m$ men and $w$ women.

Note that once you know the position of, say, the women, then everything is fixed. So the problem comes down to place $w$ women at $m + w$ "spots", and the number of ways is
$$
{m + w \choose w} = \frac{(m + n)!}{m!\,n!}.
$$
For example, if $w=3$ and $m=2$ there are 10 ways.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks! (: